# Is there a function that converts unix timestamps into just the hour variables in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unix-timestamp

I'm new to python, so this may seem obvious, but I'm trying to replace a column in a dataframe named unix_timestamp with the hours for the specific unix_timestamp. EX: [1326429793] would turn into [4]

I tried using the panda method to_datetime but it doesn't do what I want.
I'm currently using the .hour in a few examples I saw online 
- datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1326429793).hour
but when applying it to a dataframe it outputs an error

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
#
traindf['hour'] = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(traindf['unix_timestamp_of_request_utc']).hour
```

The above code returns the TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'int'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please show us a sample of `traindf`. Here's an excellent post detailing how to make a good reproducible pandas question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
traindf['hour'] = traindf['unix_timestamp_of_request_utc'].apply(pd.Timestamp.utcfromtimestamp).dt.hour
```

Also, pd.Timestamp has its own utcfromtimestamp method.

Comment: you may need to convert it to int first : traindf['unix_timestamp_of_request_utc'] = traindf['unix_timestamp_of_request_utc'].astype(int) then the apply